# How to create a new list for every scanned discipline in Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I want to print a list with the following information:

| Discipline | Grades | Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Discipline 1 | Grade 1, Grade 2, Grade 3, | Average Discipline 1 |
| Discipline 2 | Grade 1, Grade 2, Grade 3, | Average Discipline 1 |

The problem is that I made only one list for grades. I don`t know how to make new list for every discipline.

I tried this:

```
package graduation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GraduationGrade {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List <String> disciplines = new ArrayList<>();
        List <Integer> disciplineGrades = new ArrayList<>();
        List <Integer> disciplineAverage = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;

        
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a discipline or type EXIT");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String discipline = sc.next();
    
            
            if(discipline.equals("EXIT")) {
                
                System.out.println("    DISCIPLINE      GRADES          AVERAGE "); 
                
                for (int j = 0; j < disciplines.size(); j++) {
                    System.out.println((j + 1) + "      " + disciplines.get(j) + "       " + disciplineGrades.get(j)+ "         " + disciplineAverage.get(j));
                }
                
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter how many grades do you have for " + discipline);
                sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                int gradeNumbers = sc.nextInt();
                
                do {
                    System.out.println("Please enter your grades for " + discipline + " one by one (between 4 and 10)");
                    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int grades = sc.nextInt();
        
                    int sum = disciplineGrades.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
                    int average= sum/gradeNumbers;
                    
                    disciplines.add(discipline);
                    disciplineGrades.add(grades);
                    disciplineAverage.add(average);
                    i++;
                    
                    
                } while(i<gradeNumbers);
                
            
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the program this is what I get:

```
Please enter a discipline or type EXIT
Math
Please enter how many grades do you have for Math
4
Please enter your grades for Math one by one (between 4 and 10)
4
Please enter your grades for Math one by one (between 4 and 10)
5
Please enter your grades for Math one by one (between 4 and 10)
6
Please enter your grades for Math one by one (between 4 and 10)
7
Please enter a discipline or type EXIT
Biology
Please enter how many grades do you have for Biology
10
Please enter your grades for Biology one by one (between 4 and 10)
8
Please enter your grades for Biology one by one (between 4 and 10)
6
Please enter your grades for Biology one by one (between 4 and 10)
7
Please enter your grades for Biology one by one (between 4 and 10)
5
Please enter your grades for Biology one by one (between 4 and 10)
4
Please enter your grades for Biology one by one (between 4 and 10)
6
Please enter a discipline or type EXIT
EXIT
DISCIPLINE      GRADES          AVERAGE 
1       Math         4      0
2       Math         5      1
3       Math         6      2
4       Math         7      3
5       Biology      8      2
6       Biology      6      3
7       Biology      7      3
8       Biology      5      4
9       Biology      4      4
10      Biology      6      5
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the source code is that it's storing all the grades for every discipline in a single list (`disciplineGrades`). Therefore, when calculating the average, it's using the sum of all grades instead of the sum of grades for the specific discipline.

To solve this problem, you need to create a list of lists to store the grades for each discipline separately. You can modify the code as follows:

```
package graduation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GraduationGrade {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> disciplines = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> disciplineGrades = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> disciplineAverages = new ArrayList<>();

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a discipline or type EXIT");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String discipline = sc.next();

            if(discipline.equals("EXIT")) {
                System.out.println("    DISCIPLINE      GRADES          AVERAGE ");
                for (int j = 0; j < disciplines.size(); j++) {
                    List<Integer> grades = disciplineGrades.get(j);
                    int sum = grades.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
                    int average = sum / grades.size();
                    System.out.println((j + 1) + "      " + disciplines.get(j) + "       " + grades.toString() + "         " + average);
                }
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter how many grades do you have for " + discipline);
                sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                int gradeNumbers = sc.nextInt();

                List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < gradeNumbers; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter your grade for " + discipline + " (between 4 and 10)");
                    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int grade = sc.nextInt();
                    grades.add(grade);
                }

                disciplines.add(discipline);
                disciplineGrades.add(grades);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code creates a `List<List<Integer>>` called `disciplineGrades` to hold the grades for each discipline. When a new discipline is added, a new empty list of grades is created and added to `disciplineGrades`. Then, when the user enters grades for that discipline, those grades are added to the corresponding list in `disciplineGrades`.

When the program is done accepting input, the average grade for each discipline is calculated by iterating over the `disciplineGrades` list, summing the grades for each discipline, and dividing by the number of grades. The averages are stored in a separate `List<Integer>` called `disciplineAverages`.

Finally, when the user enters "EXIT", the program prints out the table of disciplines, grades, and averages by iterating over the `disciplines`, `disciplineGrades`, and `disciplineAverages` lists, retrieving the corresponding values for each discipline, and printing them out in the desired format.

The final output would be as follows.

```
Please enter a discipline or type EXIT
Math
Please enter how many grades do you have for Math
4
Please enter your grade for Math (between 4 and 10)
4
Please enter your grade for Math (between 4 and 10)
5
Please enter your grade for Math (between 4 and 10)
6
Please enter your grade for Math (between 4 and 10)
7
Please enter a discipline or type EXIT
Biology
Please enter how many grades do you have for Biology
10
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
4
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
5
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
6
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
7
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
8
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
9
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
4
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
5
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
6
Please enter your grade for Biology (between 4 and 10)
7
Please enter a discipline or type EXIT
EXIT
    DISCIPLINE      GRADES          AVERAGE 
1      Math       [4, 5, 6, 7]         5
2      Biology       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7]         6
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't place the Scanner declaration into the `while` loop. Upon each `while` loop iteration, you are declaring a new Scanner object. You only need the one Scanner, so declare it in the members area so that it can be used globally throughout the entire class. You are also declaring a new Scanner for ever prompt (`sc = new Scanner(System.in);`)... try not to do that.

Instead of using a bunch of Lists, use one List of Discipline (`List<Discipline>`). Create a **Discipline** object class instead and use that for your **one** List.

It's also a good idea to validate a User's entry within all prompts to that User so as not to encounter any errors down the road. You will notice in the supplied runnable code, I like to only use the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method for all alpha, numerical, or alphanumerical entry prompts. This however, is a personal choice since I find it to be the most flexible and I don't need to utilize *Try/Catch* mechanisms for prompt validations.

The runnable code below makes use of a Discipline class. Although in the demo code below, it is an *inner class*, it should really be a **.java** class file of its own. Here is the runnable code. Be sure to read all the comments in code. If you like, You can delete those comments when you are done with them since too many comments can be rather obtrusive.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GraduationGrade {
    
    // Member variables:
    // OS related newline character sequence.
    private final String ls = System.lineSeparator();
    
    /* Open a keyboard input Stream. Do not close. The JVM
       will close this resource automatically when the app
       closes.                     */
    private final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    /* List of available school courses that can be entered by 
       the User. This is used for Discipline entry validation.
       Any courses can be added or removed from this list.  */
    private final List<String> coursesList = Arrays.asList(
            "English", "Math", "Art", "Science", "History", "Music",
            "Geography", "P.E.", "Drama", "Biology", "Chemistry",
            "Physics", "I.T.", "Foreign Languages", "Social Studies", 
            "Technology", "Philosophy", "Graphic Design", "Literature",
            "Algebra", "Geometry"
        );
    
    
    // Application start entry point method:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need for statics
           except where desired.        */
        new GraduationGrade().StartApp(args);  // See the `startApp()` method.
    }

    private void StartApp(String[] args) {
        /* List Interface of Discipline (List<Discipline>) to hold all 
           instances of created disciplines.        */
        List<Discipline> disciplinesList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // Variable to hold Discipline Number (ID):
        int idx = 0;
        
        // Variable to hold current discipline name (Math, Art, Biology, etc):
        String discipline;

        // Main Outer `while` loop (enter 'e' to print table and exit this loop:
        while (true) {
            discipline = ""; // Initialize `discipline` to hold Null String:
            
            // Prompt for Discipline Name (Math, Art, Biology, etc):
            while (discipline.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a Discipline (e to exit): -> ");
                discipline = userInput.nextLine().trim();  // Get User input:
                
                // Validate Input...
                boolean haveIt = false; // Flag

                /* Check User supplied discipline name with what is contained
                   within the `coursesList` List:          */
                for (String course : coursesList) {
                    // If the discipline name exist in List then...
                    if (discipline.equalsIgnoreCase(course)) {
                        haveIt = true;       // set flag to boolean true
                        /* Set `discipline` to what it's named within the
                           `coursesList` List. It will be assumed that the
                           `coursesList` will contain proper letter case
                           for the discipline at hand.                  */
                        discipline = course;  
                        break; // Since found, break out of this `for` loop.
                    }
                }
                
                /* If the provided discipline name does not exist and
                   the provided discipline name is not the letter 'e'
                   inform of invalid entry and permit the User to view
                   all available courses that can be entered.      */
                if (!haveIt && !discipline.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Discipline Entry (" + discipline + ")! Not In Course List!");
                    String listIt = "";
                    while (listIt.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.print("Enter 'List' to see course list or just ENTER to skip: -> ");
                        listIt = userInput.nextLine().trim();  // Get User input:
                        if (listIt.isEmpty()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (listIt.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
                            /* Display the available Courses that can be entered as a
                               four column sorted list within the console window:  */
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("Available Courses:" + ls + "==================");
                            Collections.sort(coursesList);
                            int cnt = 0;
                            for (String clst : coursesList) {
                                System.out.printf("%-20s", clst);
                                cnt++;
                                if (cnt == 4) {
                                    System.out.println();
                                    cnt = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println(ls);
                        }
                        else {
                            // Otherwise just indicate an Invalid Entry and allow User to try again:
                            System.out.println("Invalid Entry (" + listIt + ")! Try again..." + ls);
                            listIt = ""; // Empty `listIt` to ensure re-loop.
                        }
                    }
                    discipline = ""; // Empty `discipline` to ensure re-loop.
                }
            }
            
            // If the code makes this far, then validation passed!
            // Was 'e' Entered?
            if (discipline.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
                // Yes...it was:
                // Display the List of Discipline to the Console Window:
                System.out.println();
                for (int d = 0; d < disciplinesList.size(); d++) {
                    if (d == 0) {
                        System.out.println(disciplinesList.get(d).toTableString(true));
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(disciplinesList.get(d).toTableString());
                    }
                }
                break; // This break will effectively end the application.
            }
            
            // Otherwise, move onto next application Prompt:
            // The Number of Grades for currently supplied Discipline:
            else {
                // PROMPT: Number of grades for supplied Discipline:
                String numOfGrades = ""; // For prompt use
                while (numOfGrades.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter how many grades do you have for '"
                            + discipline + "': -> ");
                    numOfGrades = userInput.nextLine().trim();  // Get User input:
                    // Validate Input...
                    /* Is the User input a string representation of a unsigned
                       integer value and is that value greater than 0?     */
                    if (!numOfGrades.matches("\\d+") && Integer.parseInt(numOfGrades) > 0) {
                        // No...Inform User of invalid entry and allow to try again:
                        System.out.println("Invalid Entry (" + numOfGrades + ")! Try Again..." + ls);
                        numOfGrades = "";   // Empty `numOfGrades` to ensure re-loop.
                    }
                }
                
                // If the code makes this far, then validation passed!
                // Convert `numOfGrades` into an int type value:
                int numberOfGrades = Integer.parseInt(numOfGrades);
                System.out.println();
                
                /* Declare a List Interface of Integer (List<Integer>) so 
                   to hold all the grades that will be entered for the 
                   supplied Discipline. This list will later be converted
                   to an int[] array so that it can be properly applied 
                   later to a Discipline instance.                */
                List<Integer> gradeList = new ArrayList<>();
                
                // PROMPT: Cycling prompt for Grades entry:
                int j = 1; // Counter used to keep track of the number of grades entered.
                // Outer loop to ensure the proper number of grades are supplied.
                while (j <= numberOfGrades) {
                    String grd = ""; // variable used for prompt input:
                    while (grd.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.print("Please enter your grade #" + j + " for "
                                        + discipline + " (between 4 and 10): -> ");
                        grd = userInput.nextLine().trim();  // Get User input:
                        
                        /* Is the User input a string representation of a signed
                           or unsigned integer value and is that value inclusively 
                           between 4 qnd 10?     */
                        if (!grd.matches("-?\\d+") && (Integer.parseInt(grd) < 4 || Integer.parseInt(grd) > 10)) {
                            // No...Inform User and allow to try again:
                            System.out.println("Invalid Grade Entry (" + grd + ")! Try Again..." + ls);
                            grd = "";   // Empty `grd` to ensure re-loop.
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // If the code makes this far, then validation passed!
                    // Convert `grd` into an int type value:
                    gradeList.add(Integer.valueOf(grd));
                    j++;  // Increment the number of grades tracker variable.
                }
                
                // Convert List<Integer> to int[] array:
                int[] grades = gradeList.stream().mapToInt(d -> d).toArray();
                
                /* Sum the supplied grades for the supplied Discipline 
                   contained within the `gradesList` List:          */
                double sum = gradeList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
                
                // Get the average for those supplied grades:
                double average = sum / numberOfGrades;

                // Create an instance of Discipline and add it to the List:
                disciplinesList.add(new Discipline((idx + 1), discipline, grades, average));
            }
            System.out.println();
            idx++;  // Increment the Discipline number:
        }
    }

    /* INNER CLASS:
       Used this way for demo purpose. Although this works, it
       would be better if it were a .java class file of it's own: */
    public class Discipline {
        // Member variables:
        private int disciplineID;
        private String disciplineName;
        private int[] grades;
        private double gradesAverage;

        // Constructor
        public Discipline(int disciplineID, String disciplineName, int[] grades, double gradesAverage) {
            this.disciplineID = disciplineID;
            this.disciplineName = disciplineName;
            this.grades = grades;
            this.gradesAverage = gradesAverage;
        }

        // Getters and Setters:
        public int getDisciplineID() {
            return disciplineID;
        }

        public void setDisciplineID(int disciplineID) {
            this.disciplineID = disciplineID;
        }

        public String getDisciplineName() {
            return disciplineName;
        }

        public void setDisciplineName(String disciplineName) {
            this.disciplineName = disciplineName;
        }

        public int[] getGrades() {
            return grades;
        }

        public void setGrades(int[] grades) {
            this.grades = grades;
        }

        public double getGradesAverage() {
            return gradesAverage;
        }

        public void setGradesAverage(double gradesAverage) {
            this.gradesAverage = gradesAverage;
        }

        /**
         * A custom toString() type method for returning Table spaced strings 
         * of instance data.
         * 
         * @param applyTheHeader (boolean - Optional - Default is false) If 
         * set to boolean true then this method will return a lined header 
         * with the table spaced instance data. This would only ever be 
         * supplied for the first call to this method unless you want the 
         * header to be applied to each line of instance data returned. if 
         * nothing is supplied then boolean false is implied.
         * 
         * @return (String)
         */
        public String toTableString(boolean...applyTheHeader) {
            boolean applyHeader = false;
            if (applyTheHeader.length > 0) {
                applyHeader = applyTheHeader[0];
            }
            String header = String.format("%-24s %-24s %-6s%n","DISCIPLINE", "GRADES", "AVERAGE");
            String tableTopLine = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length() - 2, "=")) + ls;
            String headerUnderline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length() - 2, "-")) + ls;
            
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            if(applyHeader) {
                sb.append(tableTopLine).append(header).append(headerUnderline);
            }
            String id = String.valueOf(this.getDisciplineID());
            String dis = String.format("%-4s%-12s", id, disciplineName);
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("");
            for (Integer n : grades) {
                if (!sb2.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    sb2.append(", ");
                }
                sb2.append(n);
            }
            String gradesStrg = sb2.toString();
            String average = String.format("%.2f", gradesAverage);
            String dataLine = String.format("%-24s %-24s %-22s", dis, gradesStrg, average);
            sb.append(dataLine);
            return sb.toString();
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return disciplineID + "; " + disciplineName + "; " 
                    + Arrays.toString(grades).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "") + "; " + gradesAverage;
        }
    }
}
```

When running this code, entries could look like....

```
Please enter a Discipline (e to exit): -> Forign Languages
Invalid Discipline Entry (Forign Languages)! Not In Course List!
Enter 'List' to see course list or just ENTER to skip: -> list

Available Courses:
==================
Algebra             Art                 Biology             Chemistry           
Drama               English             Foreign Languages   Geography           
Geometry            Graphic Design      History             I.T.                
Literature          Math                Music               P.E.                
Philosophy          Physics             Science             Social Studies      
Technology          

Please enter a Discipline (e to exit): -> Foreign Languages
Please enter how many grades do you have for 'Foreign Languages': -> 4

Please enter your grade #1 for Foreign Languages (between 4 and 10): -> 4
Please enter your grade #2 for Foreign Languages (between 4 and 10): -> 5
Please enter your grade #3 for Foreign Languages (between 4 and 10): -> 6
Please enter your grade #4 for Foreign Languages (between 4 and 10): -> 7

Please enter a Discipline (e to exit): -> Music
Please enter how many grades do you have for 'Music': -> 3

Please enter your grade #1 for Music (between 4 and 10): -> 7
Please enter your grade #2 for Music (between 4 and 10): -> 8
Please enter your grade #3 for Music (between 4 and 10): -> 9

Please enter a Discipline (e to exit): -> Biology
Please enter how many grades do you have for 'Biology': -> 5

Please enter your grade #1 for Biology (between 4 and 10): -> 5
Please enter your grade #2 for Biology (between 4 and 10): -> 6
Please enter your grade #3 for Biology (between 4 and 10): -> 7
Please enter your grade #4 for Biology (between 4 and 10): -> 8
Please enter your grade #5 for Biology (between 4 and 10): -> 9

Please enter a Discipline (e to exit): -> e

=========================================================
DISCIPLINE               GRADES                   AVERAGE
---------------------------------------------------------
1   Foreign Languages    4, 5, 6, 7               5.50                  
2   Music                7, 8, 9                  8.00                  
3   Biology              5, 6, 7, 8, 9            7.00
```